# Installation R and the library "dtw" on Linux Mint

Tags: r, debian

Is it possible to use Rstudio and the library "dtw" on Linux Mint?
I have an error message: dependencies 'proxy' missing, which seems to need R>3.3 but it isn't disponible from the package manager (I'm on 3.2).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to update R. You say you're on Mint so go here https://cran.r-project.org and choose download R for Linux then choose either Ubuntu or Debian depending on the version of mint you're running and follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: This is assuming mint is still based on Ubuntu. I haven't used mint in years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's based on Debian. Is there a way to add the latest cran repository to my package manager? Ok, I guess I've found it: deb https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran34/ ??

Comment: Looking into it it's like I remember. The standard Linux Mint is still based on Ubuntu so you'd want to figure out which version of Ubuntu your version of Mint is based on and then follow the Ubuntu instructions to update R.  If you're using LMDE then follow the debian instructions.